# How to enable Selected Time period always when I tap on the series inside Highstock chart?

Tags: highcharts

I am using highstock chart for displaying the stock chart.when charts gets loaded by default i am showing 6M button selected.

```
rangeSelector: {
 buttons: [{
                    type: 'day',
                    count: 1,
                    text: '1min'
                }, {
                    type: 'day',
                    count: 5,
                    text: '10min'
                }, {
                    type: 'month',
                    count: 6,
                    text: '6M'
                },
{
                    type: 'year',
                    count: 3,
                    text: '3yr'
                }, {
                    type: 'year',
                    count: 10,
                    text: '10yr'
                }
                    ],
                    inputEnabled: false,
                    selected: 2

                },
```

The chart contains lot of data points.So when i tap to another spot on the series, the time period above loses the "boldness". Hence i no longer know what was the time period i had selected.

[image]

If the chart contains only 3 buttons then its working fine. If more buttons then the button is disable.
Can you tell me how to enable the selected button always when i tap on series of highstock chart?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I opened this example http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/basic-line/gray and click on the buttons, and bold doesn't disappear. Which version of HS do you use? Could you prepare your example as live demo?

Comment: I have tried with above link..just drag the chart right or left side then the selected button(bold) will be disappear.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution is not supported, but you can request this suggestion in our [uservoice system](http://highcharts.uservoice.com/)